# Standardising shadow length on sundials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, time, geometry

The sundial is fundamentally flawed in that the length of each hourly shadow changes with the seasons. If the base of the sundial was engineered to move cyclically on an anual basis however, the length could presumably be adjusted so that the shadow lengths were the same for each day. What sort of curve would the base have to follow in order for this to be achieved?

Comment: It would depend on where you currently are. The change is different  if you are somewhere in say Russia as compared to somewhere like Hawaii or near the equator.

Comment: I fail to see how that's a flaw. So long as the shadow points in the correct direction, the sundial is doing exactly what it's supposed to do.  In fact, you could use the shadow **length** to determine the day-of-year while using the shadow **angle** to determine time-of-day.

Comment: @Horus good oint. Would be happy to accept an answer based on an arbitrarily chosen geographical point.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft ok, point accepted. Flaw or not, hoever, the question still stands.

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't know whether this is relevant, but this is not homework - just curiosity ;)

Comment: Hi martin. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic thank you very much - yes it fits perfectly to `any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself` catagory - apologies! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin, and welcome to the fun house.

First, the sundial is more flawed than you think, since the earth's orbit is elliptical rather than circular. The combination of tilted axis and eccentricity shows up in shape of the analemma[image]

This particular version was made by taking pictures at a fixed time (probably early morning), at weekly intervals (with 3 points missed due to weather). Note a few things.

1) The apparent horizontal position of the sun at any fixed time varies, so a simple sundial will not produce an accurate time based on shadow angle. As you might guess, this is deterministic and can be compensated for: the compensation is determined by the **equation of time** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time and a graphic version of the equation is sometimes included on high-quality sundials
[image]

2) Except for the equinoxes and solstices, any vertical angle (and consequently the length of the sundial shadow), occurs on two different days. So a simple measurement of the shadow angle will not accurately determine the date.

Of course, this sort of complexity is just a challenge for some folk, and in 1959 Scientific American's "Amateur Scientist", Richard L. Schmoyer, showed how to make a gnomon which will allow a sundial accuracy of 1 minute over the entire year http://www.precisionsundials.com/sunquest%20article/amateur.htm

This gives an idea of how it's done, although the exact shape of the gnomon is not numerically specified, and an armillary sphere is used rather than a standard sundial:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer (& welcome!) - I haver never heard of a gnomon - thanks for the details & links :)

Comment: And I bet you've never heard of a wabe, either.

Comment: 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves ...

Comment: And, like a gnomon, it's part of a sundial (in the larger sense).